# Auto-width of ComboBox's content

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

Does anybody know a way to set the `ComboBox`'s content's width to autosize

I do not mean the `ComboBox` itself, just the opened content.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can't use it directly.

**Do a trick**

First iterate through all items of your combobox, check for the width of every items by assigning the text to a label. Then, check width every time, if width of current item gets greater than previous items then change the maximum width.

```
int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
    int maxWidth = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    Label label1 = new Label();

    foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
    {
        label1.Text = obj.ToString();
        temp = label1.PreferredWidth;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    label1.Dispose();
    return maxWidth;           
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DropDownWidth = DropDownWidth(comboBox1);
}
```

---

**OR**

As suggested by **stakx**, you can use `TextRenderer` class

```
int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
    int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
    foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
    {
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(obj.ToString(), myCombo.Font).Width;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: +1, nice answer. Without having tried this out, I'm curious: Is `label1.PreferredWidth` already computed correctly right after setting `label1.Text`? (After all, the UI won't get a chance to update itself while this code is running. I realise that `label1` isn't actually added to any form, but nevertheless... I'm surprised that this should work.)

Comment: @stakx, I tried with `label1.Width` but it was not working, since it was not added to UI. So, I used `label1.PreferredWidth`. :)

Comment: On a related note, I guess that while this trick with `label1.PreferredWidth` might work just fine, a slightly more direct and "expressive" way of measuring text width would be to use [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx)...?

Comment: i tried it on a combobox that didn't needed it, and it streched anyway, any ideas why?

Comment: i tried setting the dropdownwidth directly to a specific value, and it ignore the value i put and making the width too big

Comment: @unicorn: I have no idea. try `maxWidth = myCombo.Width;` inplace of `maxWidth = 0`.

Comment: tried that, the combobox's width is 106, and I did combobox1.DropDownWidth=40, and it's ovverlapping. for some reason setting the dropdownwidth force it to ovverlap

Comment: @unicorn: I think you are trying to make your Dropdown less than the width of Combobox. You can't make it less than combobox width.

Comment: LINQ one liner: (from object item in comboBox.Items select TextRenderer.MeasureText(item.ToString(), comboBox.Font).Width).Max();

Comment: `obj.ToString()` is not a correct text for data-bound combo-boxes.

Comment: I prefer the LINQ query: `comboBox1.DropDownWidth = comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Max(x => TextRenderer.MeasureText(x, comboBox1.Font).Width);`

Comment: if anyone ins conserned with speed i tested them with 11 items and a stopwatch and got the label at 50ms and textrender at 42ms the label was inclosed in a using though. :) but cool example javed!

Comment: `obj.ToString()` can be different than the `DisplayMember` property of the combobox. `myCombo.GetItemText(obj)` is definitely more correct than the other answers

Comment: Here's a one-liner using `GetItemText`: 
`comboBox1.DropDownWidth = comboBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Max(o => TextRenderer.MeasureText(comboBox1.GetItemText(o), comboBox1.Font).Width);`

Answer (score 22):

obj.ToString() doesn't work for me, I suggest to use myCombo.GetItemText(obj). This works for me:

```
private int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
    int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
    foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
    {
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(myCombo.GetItemText(obj), myCombo.Font).Width;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. `myCombo.GetItemText(obj)` is definitely more correct than the other answers. `obj.ToString()` can be different than the `DisplayMember` property of the combobox.

Answer (score 19):

Here is very elegant solution. Just subscribe your combobox to this event handler:

```
 private void AdjustWidthComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            int width = senderComboBox.DropDownWidth;
            Graphics g = senderComboBox.CreateGraphics();
            Font font = senderComboBox.Font;

            int vertScrollBarWidth = (senderComboBox.Items.Count > senderComboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
                    ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

            var itemsList = senderComboBox.Items.Cast<object>().Select(item => item.ToString());

            foreach (string s in itemsList)
            {
                int newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(s, font).Width + vertScrollBarWidth;

                if (width < newWidth)
                {
                    width = newWidth;
                }
            }

            senderComboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
        }
```

This code was taken from the codeproject: [Adjust combo box drop down list width to longest string width](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s).
But I have modified it to work with comboboxes filled with any data (not only strings).

Comment: +1 for accounting for vertical scroll bar width and allowing any contents, not just strings. Pity not to use TextRenderer class as in the other answers though.

Comment: You should remember to dispose the `Graphics` instance right after use, best by wrapping it inside a `using` block.

Comment: I like this solution but I wanted to change the width of the ComboBox also and it looked wierd seeing the width change after clicking the drop-down. Because I was adding the ComboBox dynamically to a FlowLayoutPanel I instead subscribed to the ParentChanged event and it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly the same code as in Javed Akram's second suggestion, but the width of the vertical scroll bar is added:

```
int setWidth_comboBox(ComboBox cb)
{
  int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
  foreach (string s in cb.Items)
  {
    temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, cb.Font).Width;
    if (temp > maxWidth)
    {
      maxWidth = temp;
    }
  }
  return maxWidth + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```

Use the code like this (on a form with a combobox with the name myComboBox):

```
myComboBox.Width = setWidth_comboBox(myComboBox);
```

Answer (score 2):

***Vote for algreat's answer below.***

I simply modified algreat's answer with code resize the entire control.

*I would have just added it as a comment but couldn't add formatted code on the comment.*

```
private void combo_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s
    ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    int width = senderComboBox.DropDownWidth;
    Graphics g = senderComboBox.CreateGraphics();
    Font font = senderComboBox.Font;
    int vertScrollBarWidth =
        (senderComboBox.Items.Count > senderComboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
        ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

    int newWidth;
    foreach (string s in ((ComboBox)sender).Items)
    {
        newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(s, font).Width
            + vertScrollBarWidth;
        if (width < newWidth)
        {
            width = newWidth;
        }

        if (senderComboBox.Width < newWidth)
        {
            senderComboBox.Width = newWidth+ SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
        }
    }
    senderComboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old but classic, hope to work fast enough

```
private int GetDropDownWidth(ComboBox combo)
{
    object[] items = new object[combo.Items.Count];
    combo.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
    return items.Select(obj => TextRenderer.MeasureText(combo.GetItemText(obj), combo.Font).Width).Max();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my solution below:

```
   private int AutoSizeDropDownWidth(ComboBox comboBox)
        {
            var width = cmboxUnit.DropDownWidth;
            var g = cmboxUnit.CreateGraphics();
            var font = cmboxUnit.Font;

            var verticalScrollBarWidth = cmboxUnit.Items.Count > cmboxUnit.MaxDropDownItems
                ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

            var itemsList = cmboxUnit.Items.Cast<object>().Select(item => item);

            foreach (DataRowView dr in itemsList)
            {
                int newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(dr["Name"].ToString(), font).Width + verticalScrollBarWidth;

                if (width < newWidth)
                {
                    width = newWidth;
                }
            }
            return width;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers is based on @user2361362 answer. The code is modified using LINQ and converted into a function that sets the drop down width of a given ComboBox:

```
private void SetComboBoxDropDownWidth(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    var width = (from object obj in comboBox.Items
            select TextRenderer.MeasureText(comboBox.GetItemText(obj), comboBox.Font).Width)
        .Prepend(0)
        .Max();
    comboBox.DropDownWidth = width + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just ran into it and combined a couple of the answers for my solution. I liked the simplicity of the accepted answer but wanted something that would work with any object type in the combo box. I also wanted to make use of the method through an extension method.

```
    public static int AutoDropDownWidth(this ComboBox myCombo)
    {
        return AutoDropDownWidth<object>(myCombo, o => o.ToString());
    }
    public static int AutoDropDownWidth<T>(this ComboBox myCombo, Func<T, string> description)
    {
        int maxWidth = 1;
        int temp = 1;
        int vertScrollBarWidth = (myCombo.Items.Count > myCombo.MaxDropDownItems)
                ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

        foreach (T obj in myCombo.Items)
        {
            if (obj is T)
            {
                T t = (T)obj;
                temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(description(t), myCombo.Font).Width;
                if (temp > maxWidth)
                {
                    maxWidth = temp;
                }
            }

        }
        return maxWidth + vertScrollBarWidth;
    }
```

This way if my class is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

I could auto adjust the combo box drop down width like this:

```
cbPeople.DropDownWidth = cbPeople.AutoDropDownWidth<Person>(p => p.FullName);
```

Answer (score -2):

TComboBox.ItemWidth is the property you seek. It has the behavior you want without any coding. Just set it at design time or programmatically to something bigger than Width, and when the user pulls down the box they will get a wider list of choices.

Comment: First of all, the question is asking for **autosize**, which is exactly the opposite of setting  a width explicitly. But secondly, it's not even clear what you mean here. What is `TComboBox`? What `ItemWidth` property is it that you are talking about? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=.NET&terms=combobox%20itemwidth turns up nothing.