# Calculate Combo Box Font Size Based on Target Height

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

We need to adjust the height of a combo box based on the height of another control. We have found that the combo box height can be adjusted by changing its font size.

How can I calculate the the font size for a Combo Box, if I know its target height?

Comment: Look at this StackOverFlow question and see if you can utilize what's been done in the `Accepted Answer` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842160/auto-width-of-comboboxs-content

Comment: This item is related to changing width. My question is about height

Comment: use the same approach and change the width value to utilize the height what's the problem..? come on now