# Sliding text in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I would like to slide the text (marquee text) of the selected item in a combobox, if it's lenght is bigger than the width of the combobox. It can be either automatical or when the user put the mouse over the combobox. The problem is that i have absolutely no idea on how to do that. It's maybe possible to do that with a render transform (previous definition of a textblock inside it)? or with a storyboard?

Here is the xaml that i need to modify

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
              <Setter.Value>
                  <DataTemplate DataType="DataGridColumnHeader"  >
                      <ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Oggetto" Width="100" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.Selezione, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

EDIT: the problem is that i don't know which properties should i target in the storyboard

EDIT2: i took the template of the combobox and modified the text box section like this :

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="00:00:10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

The problem is that this seems to have no effect

EDIT 3: i realized that i had to use the template that use the style i mentioned above

```
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
               Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent"
                                           MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                           MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Placement}">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                        BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                           Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                           Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                              RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                 IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" >
            </TextBox>
                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="true" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5" />
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

the textbox section is the one that use the style. However when i do `Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"` in the combobox, i cannot see the selected item anymore, even if it's not null

Comment: Storyboards are definitely the way to go. Have you tried anything with Storyboards?

Comment: Not really, since i never used them. Before trying anything i wanted to know which control would fit to solve my problem

Comment: Would you consider using a popup? Say when the length of an item is greater than 30 (for example) show `ToolTip` with the entire text included.

Comment: A tooltip is my plan B. I just wanted to do something different. I'm currently studying how to modify the " PART_EditableTextBox " of a combobox

Comment: I see, well you are looking into right parts. I think `ComboBox` is using the same Template to display selected item and the items in the drop down. So this might be tricky. You can always subscribe to the selection changed event and try code behind to scroll the Text in the `TextBox`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX it indeed use the same template for the items. I need to manipulate the normal template used by the combobox. The problem that i have now is exposed in the main topic. However, as far as i know, you can't operate directly on the textbox using code behind since SelectionBoxItem is a readonly property of the combobox

Comment: I have found a `XAML` solution for scrolling text [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002271/2029607) and I also found the `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` this is perhaps something that you could use. Also try to make use of the `DropDownOpened` and `Closed`.

Comment: isn't SelectionBoxItemTemplate a readonly property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 08/02**

Basically in order to avoid the animation issues you are facing - you will need to add a `ScrollViewer` as a wrapper to the content-site or selection-box `TextBlock`. You can either do that by using a custom template selector for your `ComboBox` so as defined below, or provide a custom item-template with `ScollViewer`.

Secondly, you can either create a custom `ComboBox` control in C# to bind the above template-selector/item-template and apply slide-animation on `MouseEnterEvent`; or implement the same in XAML itself.

For this example - have implemented the control in C#, and provided 
a sample usage in XAML.

### Code for custom control, and template selector

```
public class SlidingComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SlideForeverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SlideForever", typeof(bool), typeof(SlidingComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
    public bool SlideForever
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SlideForeverProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SlideForeverProperty, value); }
    }

    protected ContentPresenter _parent;
    protected DoubleAnimation _animation;
    protected TranslateTransform _translate;
    protected Storyboard _storyBoard;

    public SlidingComboBox()
    {
        Loaded += ExComboBox_Loaded;
        ClipToBounds = true;

        //assign template selector - just to re-template ContentSite / selection box 
        //uncomment this code - if you want to default-template for popup-items
        //ItemTemplateSelector = new SlidingComboBoxItemTemplateSelector();        
    }

    private void ExComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= ExComboBox_Loaded;

        //get content-site holder/parent
        _parent = this.GetChildOfType<ContentPresenter>();

        //setup slide animation
        _animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            RepeatBehavior = SlideForever ? RepeatBehavior.Forever : new RepeatBehavior(1), //repeat only if slide-forever is true
            AutoReverse = SlideForever
        };

        //create storyboard
        _storyBoard = new Storyboard();
        _storyBoard.Children.Add(_animation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_animation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //get actual textblock that renders the selected value
        var textBlock = _parent.GetChildOfType<TextBlock>();
        //and translate-transform for animation
        textBlock.RenderTransform = _translate = new TranslateTransform();

        //start animation only if text-block width is greater than parent
        if (_parent.ActualWidth < textBlock.ActualWidth)
        {
            _animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(((int)textBlock.Text?.Length * 100));
            _animation.To = _parent.ActualWidth - textBlock.ActualWidth;
            _storyBoard.Begin(textBlock);
        }

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //stop animation once mouse pointer is off the control
        _storyBoard.Stop();

        //reset render state
        var textBlock = _parent.GetChildOfType<TextBlock>();
        textBlock.RenderTransform = _translate = new TranslateTransform();

        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }

}

public class SlidingComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    DataTemplate _selectedItemTemplate;

    public SlidingComboBoxItemTemplateSelector()
    {
        //create datatemplate with ScrollViewer and TextBlock as child
        var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.NoWrap);
        textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("SelectedValue")
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(ComboBox) }
        });
        var scrollViewer = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ScrollViewer));
        scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, true);
        scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
        scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
        scrollViewer.AppendChild(textBlock);

        _selectedItemTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = scrollViewer
        };
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = container.GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>();
        if (comboBoxItem == null)
        {
            //send back only if template requested for ContentSite, and not for combo-box item(s)
            return _selectedItemTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// VisualTree helper
/// </summary>
public static class HelperExtensions
{
    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static T GetVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : Visual
    {
        while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
        {
            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        }
        return child as T;
    }
}
```

### Sample usage:

[image: sample output]

```
<Window x:Class="MarqueeSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MarqueeSample"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="225" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <col:Hashtable>
                    <col:ArrayList x:Key="TestData1">
                        <sys:String>Tiny</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Keep calm and love programming</sys:String>
                    </col:ArrayList>
                    <col:ArrayList x:Key="TestData2">
                        <sys:String>Sample string</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Another string to test</sys:String>
                    </col:ArrayList>
                </col:Hashtable>
            </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:SlidingComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                                <local:SlidingComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </local:SlidingComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </local:SlidingComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can also use SlideForever property to manipulate RepeatBehaviour.

```
<local:SlidingComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" SlideForever="True" />
```

Comment: I gave you the bounty cause it works at 99%. The only problem is that i have this exception : Cannot set both ItemTemplateSelector and Display member path. When one is nonempty, it must be cleared before the other can be set

Comment: AS far as i understand is because basically, DisplayMemberPath is an ItemTemplate. So i guess i should add a binding inside the template selector?

Comment: I fixed overwriting the item template in xaml, while keeping your custom event. Thanks again

Comment: @DanieleSartori You are right - we can use custom ItemTemplate with combo-box instead of template-selector - but you need to make sure that your custom template has a ScrollViewer for the animation to work; I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this and I think I have your solution. You should combine both a `RenderTransform` and a `Storyboard` on the `ComboBox` `ContentPresenter` (this is what displays the currently selected item)

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Name="MyComboBox" Width="200">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ScrollItem">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:5" From="0" To="200" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:5" BeginTime="00:00:5" From="-200" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            I am combobox value 1
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            I am combobox value 2, Hello!
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Having the ComboBox of size 200, scrolling from 0 to 200, then -200 to 0, scrolls the text off the right hand side of the control, and in the left hand side. (You can drop the 2nd `DoubleAnimation` if you like and set `AutoReverse` to True to cause the text to bounce back in if you'd rather that. This does not code you around items that are too big for the control, you will need to write some code for the ComboBox so it decides if the currently selected Item is too big, and from code behind (or maybe a custom ComboBox Class) dynamically turn on/off the storyboard.

Comment: this is almost working. However i don't get why the text is still cut even when scrolling.

Comment: I think that even if the text scroll, since my comboboxes are part of the datagrid header, some strange effect happens:  1- the text scroll but stay cut (like when it is displayed in the box) 2- If you select more then one item, they all scroll, but in thole row, they are not limited to the single combobox which they belong (see the figures in the link) http://imgur.com/mfNoM1d

Comment: I've set the Event to be on Window Load so they just scroll forever. RenderTransform actually manipulates purely the rendered output, the problem is that all the layout based decisions (including how much text should be clipped) it made before the RenderTransform is applied. This is tricky... I feel like a Custom ComboBox class that makes its own decision on text to write is going to be the best path forward.

Answer (score -2):

First iterate through all items of your combobox, check for the width of every items by assigning the text to a label. Then, check width every time, if width of current item gets greater than previous items then change the maximum width.

```
   int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
   {
   int maxWidth = 0;
   int temp = 0;
   Label label1 = new Label();

   foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
   {
       label1.Text = obj.ToString();
       temp = label1.PreferredWidth;
       if (temp > maxWidth)
       {
           maxWidth = temp;
       }
   }
   label1.Dispose();
   return maxWidth;           
}

private void window_loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DropDownWidth = DropDownWidth(comboBox1);
}
```

OR

```
int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
     int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
     foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
     {
         temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(obj.ToString(), myCombo.Font).Width;
         if (temp > maxWidth)
         {
             maxWidth = temp;
         }
     }
     return maxWidth;
 }
```

Thanks to those guys got it from here --> [Auto-width of ComboBox's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842160/auto-width-of-comboboxs-content)

Comment: If i understand correctly you are proposing to increase the width of the combobox itself. However that is not what i need. I need the combobox to stay as it is, only the text inside the combobox (not inside the dropdown), i.e. the selected item, should slide (because if it's lenght is greater than the combobox width, then the text will be seen cutted)

Comment: Your Example is for `WinForms` NOT `WPF`.

Comment: Im aware of that but there are hardly differences so i thought it is not that bad

Comment: Perhaps you could re-work your answer to one that works in WPF as the question asks