# How to resize width of suggest list when typing in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I would like to ask about to fit the width of suggest list. For the dropdown list, I'm following this topic
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s
This runs perfectly. But when I'm typing something,a suggest list apprears and it doesn't show all my content value.

[image]

How can I fit the size with content automatically.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey maybe this post helps you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842160/auto-width-of-comboboxs-content)

Comment: Hi Kielmann,
This solution in links work when pulling down the content by setting the DropDownWidth. But It doesn't work for suggest list.